# Python Funktion calling

Tags: python, function, maya

Does anybody know how to call the function outside of the function.

In other function i would like to call only the printed(InnerEdge), not the whole function.

[image]

Comment: Make it a function you can use in both places

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: I'm continuously amazed how screenshoting and uploading an image is for some easier then copying & pasting text into the question...

Answer (score 1):

Create new function, for that one.
for example:

```
def outputter(inner_edge):
   print (inner_edge)
```

then you can call it, from every function you want:

```
def IE(*arg):
   *piece of your code
    innerEdge = ...
    if BUTTON:
       outputter(innerEdge)

def another_function(*arg):
   *piece of your code
    innerEdge = ...
    if BUTTON:
       outputter(innerEdge)
```

Comment: This could've been just ```outputter = print```. Anyway that's just aliasing ```print``` to ```outputter```  and I don't think that's what they meant.